# how to convert the following while loop into a for loop?

Tags: python

I am not able to understand how to deal with this problem without pre-assigning 50 to a variable which I tried earlier and it worked (I mean pre-assigning a value of 50 to a variable)

```
x=50 
while x>=10:
     print(x)
     x=x-5
#it should be done without pre-assigning a varible with the value 50
```

Comment: Hey this does not solve your problem, but reading on the provided link might help
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use python's `range` command to decrease from 50. The first argument for `range` is the start number (inclusive). The second is the end number (exclusive, which is why I used 9 below, not 10. If I'd used 10, the range wouldn't have included 10). The last argument is the the increment, in this case, decreasing be 5 each time.

```
for x in range(50,9,-5):
    print(x)
```

The for loop with iterate over every value in the range. In this case `range(50,9,-5)` includes 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, and 10